# Convolution inequality on stochastic cadlag functions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $K$ be a not differentiable kernel, $\sigma$ a (at least) $C^1$ function, Lipschitz of constant $L > 0$, $X_s, Y_s$ two cadlag processes.

Let $f(t,s,X_{\cdot})$ a measurable function and indicate with $f_1$ the derivate of $f$ in the first variable  ($t$). 
Can we say that 
$$\sup_{u<s}\left|f_1(t,u,X_{\cdot})-f_1(t,u,Y_{\cdot}) \right|\leq C \sup_{u<s}|X_s-Y_s|$$
for some constant $C$?

Is there a way to exploit the regularity of $\sigma$ and bypass the not differentiability of $K$?

Comment: I have tried to use lebesgue points and I have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{1}{\omega_r}\int_{B(x,r)}|\frac{d}{dt}K(t-s)\sigma(X_{s})-\frac{d}{dt}K(t-s)\sigma(Y_{s})|ds
 \\&=\frac{1}{\omega_r}\int_{B(x,r)}|K(s)\frac{d}{dt}\sigma(X_{t-s})-K(s)\frac{d}{dt}\sigma(Y_{t-s})|ds
 \\&\le\frac{1}{\omega_r}\int_{B(x,r)}|K(s)||\frac{d}{dt}(\sigma(X_{t-s})-\sigma(Y_{t-s}))|ds
\end{align*}
but it doesn't seem to work